# How can i modify server_util.py file of streamlit package for my heroku app?

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

I got this message when using my deployed app in heroku: "RuntimeError: Data of size 62.1MB exceeds write limit of 50.0MB". I fixed this issue in my desktop by changing the parameter MESSAGE_LIMIT_SIZE to 100*1e6 in ~/site-packages/streamlit/server/server_util.py, but i don't know how to do the same in my deployed app.

Answer (score 1):

We recently introduced some changes with 1.4.0 to fix this problem. The default message size limit is now 200 MB (instead of 50 MB) and you can increase it even further with the config option `server.maxMessageSize`. More about config options [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/configuration). Let me know if this works or not!